# Check if BuildRowsetFromString insert a special number

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have a Field in my DataExtension which include a row of number. For example `2,212,314,426`.

With **BuildRowsetFromString** i'm able to separate the fields, that's fine!

Now i want to check if (e.g.) the number `314` is include in this row. If yes I want to output a different text.

```
%%[
SET @test = "2,212,314,426"
SET @test2 = Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromString(@test, ","), 1), 1)
IF @test2 == 314 THEN

SET @text = "Output Text 1"
ELSE
SET @text = "Output Text 2"
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@text)=%%
```

Now, i can check the first number but i don't know how to check the whole row.

I very thankful for help :)

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Yes the code worked! Thank u Adam. My Problem was that the Database include no Primary Key. Without that Key AMPscript will not filter any queries.. so from now everything worked.

Comment: Sweet. Please mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since `BuildRowSetFromString()` returns a rowset, you'll need iterate through the values to determine if it contains a specific value.

Also, you're dealing with strings, not number, so there's some type conversion that needs to be done.  Using the `Add()` function will convert it to a number.

```
%%[

var @i, @test, @rows, @row, @text

SET @test = "2,212,314,426"
SET @rows = BuildRowSetFromString(@test, ",")

set @text = ""

for @i = 1 to rowcount(@rows) do

  set @row = row(@rows,@i)
  set @test2 = field(@row,1)
  outputline(concat("<br>@i:",@i, ", @test2: ",@test2))

  set @test2 = add(@test2,0)

  if empty(@text) then

    if @test2 == 314 THEN
      SET @text = "Output Text 1"
    endif

  endif

next @i

set @text = iif(empty(@text),"Output Text 2",@text)

]%%

<br>%%=v(@text)=%%
```

**Output:**

```
@i:1, @test2: 2 
@i:2, @test2: 212 
@i:3, @test2: 314 
@i:4, @test2: 426 
Output Text 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be able to set a filter for the loop?

I have a string with i want to explode.. that worked but all values lower than "0" i don't want to display.

thats my code:

```
%%[
var @subjects, @onesubject, @i
set @subjects = "212, 345, 512, 000, 000, 000"
set @onesubject = BuildRowsetFromString(@subjects,',')

for @i = 1 to rowcount(@onesubject) do
set @row = row(@onesubject,@i)
set @v = field(@row, 1)

if @v > 100 THEN
set @text = "bigger than 100"
else
set @text = "smaller than 100"
]%%

Text: %%=v(@text)=%% <br>
<br>
%%[ next @i ]%%
```

And thats my Output:

```
Interesse: 212
Text A

Interesse: 345
Text A

Interesse: 512
Text A

Interesse:

Interesse:

Interesse:
```

Would it be able to only display values greater than 0?